# Python multitprocessing outputs in order?

Tags: python, file, queue, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing to do a large number of calculations on a set of data to decrease the calculation time. It's working fantastically, except for one small caveat, when I have my listener process writing my outputs, it comes out in the wrong order, which is decidely bad. I need it to all come out in the same order it's going in. Not sure how to achieve this. Sample code is below.

```
import numpy, os, multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value, Array, RawArray, RawValue
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def domorestuff(value):
    value += value # sample, some other calculation
    q.put(value)
    return

def dostuff(somevalue):
    somevalue += 1 # do some calculation instead of just +=1 here
    domorestuff(somevalue)
    return

def listener(q):
    f = open(os.path.join(outdir, fileout.value), 'w')
    while 1:
        #print("Listener...", flush=True)
        m = q.get()
        if(m == 'kill'):
            break
        #print("Listen write...", flush=True)
        f.write(str(m) + '\n')
        f.flush()
    f.close()

def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(9)
    watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))
    pool.map(dostuff, range(8))
    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
```

I'd expect it to give me a linear set of values in the file, i.e.:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18
```

But instead they come out in a random order every time. At a loss how to sync things up, when I don't use a listener and am not doing file writing, it seems to join processes by the number of threads, in order. But it is hard to tell for sure, since I can't safely write the output from many threads to a single file.

To make it a bit more clear the processing happens to an input file, which each thread reads the part it needs, and then writes an output based on the processing to the listener. But rather than getting the chunks in order, as mentioned above it comes out in random ordered chunks.

Answer (score 0):

you are running your processes asynchronously. You cannot expect that these independent processes process/finish their task in any expected order.

Comment: Only the file writing item is run asynchronously, while the other processes are not. Since they are not asynchronous they should finish and submit queue requests in order according to the documentation on the `pool.map` function.

Answer (score 0):

@M.Rau is not actually right, you could run the jobs in the pool and join them back together preserving the order, and luckily the `multiprocessing` module has this feature build in using either `pool.apply_async` or `pool.imap`.

I cleaned your code a little bit (note that the queue is completely gone) and this is what i came up with:

```
import numpy, os, multiprocessing

def domorestuff(value):
    return value + value # sample, some other calculation

def dostuff(somevalue):
    somevalue += 1 # do some calculation instead of just +=1 here
    return domorestuff(somevalue)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(9)
    out = list(pool.imap(dostuff, range(8)))
    pool.close()
    print (out)
```

For more information take a look at [an example from the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#examples). They have different techniques explained right there. By the way your python code from the question does not even compile and the listener function is irrelevant. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The issue here is that a lot of the data I'm working on and outputting is very large, including several gigabyte files that I can't just have the code wholly storing in memory all the time.
Additionally, since the code tends to run for a few hours at a time, any interruption is bad, so I need to be able to write items to disk during the processing so I can recover where it left off if needed.
Regarding the listener function, it is not irrelevant, it fires when `q.put()` is used. I'm not sure why it's not compiling for you, but perhaps I made a transcription error as its retyped from other PC